# Pandas: How to combine suffixed columns after a merge?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

**Background**

1. There is a CSV that contains data in the following format:

   - timestamp, col 1, col 2, etc.
2. A Python script periodically queries an API and adds to this CSV.
3. To do this, the CSV is loaded into a dataframe, and the data to be added is loaded into a dataframe. The timestamp column is made the index of each dataframe.
4. Sometimes when updating the CSV, for some reason I'm not aware of, there will already be a row in the CSV that contains the same timestamp as one of the rows in the new data.
5. These rows which share a timestamp (one in the CSV and one in the new data), when they exist, will always differ in which other columns they have values for.

**The task**

How can these rows which share a timestamp be combined into a single row, using Pandas?

When using the `merge` function to merge the two dataframes, the columns which overlap are saved separately, with suffixes (`_x` and `_y`) to tell them apart.

**Example**

Here's the code I was given:

```
# this is an example of the code I have but it isn't working properly
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

csv_data = 'example.csv'

timenow = datetime.now()

# reads dataframe from example.csv
historical_df = pd.read_csv(csv_data)
historical_df.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)

# gets new data from API ### 1st API call
new_data = pd.DataFrame([timenow, 1234]).T
new_data.columns = ['timestamp', 'col 1']

new_data.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)

# Concat current data to historical DF and dump to excel
updated_df = pd.concat([historical_df, new_data])

# Save to CSV
updated_df.to_csv(csv_data)


### 2nd API call with the same time
# reads dataframe from example.csv
historical_df = pd.read_csv(csv_data)
historical_df.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)

# gets new data from API
new_data = pd.DataFrame([timenow, 5678]).T
new_data.columns = ['timestamp', 'col 2']

new_data.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)

# Concat current data to historical DF and dump to excel
updated_df = pd.concat([historical_df, new_data])

# Save to CSV
updated_df.to_csv(csv_data)
```

Contents of 'example.csv':

```
timestamp          col 1    col 2
9/01/2018 12:15    3610     2420.29
```

Example desired output:

```
timestamp            col 1      col 2
9/01/2018 12:15      3610       2420.29
<the new timestamp>  1234       5678
```

What using `concat` results in:

```
timestamp            col 1      col 2
9/01/2018 12:15      3610       2420.29
<the new timestamp>  1234       
<the new timestamp>             5678
```

What using `merge` results in:

```
timestamp            col 1_x   col 1_y   col 2_x    col 2_y
9/01/2018 12:15      3610                2420.29
<the new timestamp>  1234                           5678
```

Note that this example only shows two non-timestamp columns, but there are actually 15 in the example I was given.

Comment: You want the new value overwriting the last?

Comment: Instead of merge, use `df2.combine_first(df1)`.

Comment: @COLDSPEED I'm not sure what you mean, but the idea is that the new row (with timestamp X) will contain values in certain columns which are empty in the existing row, and will have blank values in columns which are filled out in the existing row (which also has timestamp X). And so the "final" row (after those two rows are combined) will contain all of the non-empty values in all of the columns of both of those rows.

Comment: Let me stop you right here. You should know that most of us in this tag understand _data_ better than english. Your neatly written post would not come nearly as close to helping us understand the problem as an actual data sample of say, 5-10 rows. So, please provide a [mcve] with some data and expected output, and please explain how it works.

Comment: Ok give me a few minutes.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I've added a simplified version of the example I was given.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. Based on your data, it would seem a simple `pd.concat([df1, df1])` would work. But if there are duplicates, then you'd want `df2.combine_first(df1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As COLDSPEED mentioned in the comments, the answer was to use `combine_first` instead of `merge`:

`df_with_merged_rows = df_with_new_data.combine_first(df_created_from_csv)`

Comment: I think you mean `df_with_new_data.combine_first(df_created_from_csv)`, because priority is given to `df_with_new_data` I believe.